# SHA1Managed UWP (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, sha

I writing app for UWP

I have code

```
 private string Hash(string input)
 {
     using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
     {
         var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
         var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);

         foreach (byte b in hash)
         {
             // can be "x2" if you want lowercase
             sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
         }

         return sb.ToString();
     }
}
```

But it not works and show this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SHA1Managed' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Milano  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\WoocommerceApiClient.cs 25  Active

How I can fix this?

Comment: The code you wrote was for .NET Framework. UWP does not support the type and you must switch to UWP's cryptography classes.

Answer (score 4):

For UWP use [`HashAlgorithmProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241511?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

```
    public string Hash(string input)
    {
        IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(input, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        HashAlgorithmProvider hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1);
        var hashByte = hashAlgorithm.HashData(buffer).ToArray();
        var sb = new StringBuilder(hashByte.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in hashByte)
        {
            sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Remember to add

```
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;
```

Comment: I get this error  IBuffer does not contain a definition for ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

SHA1Managed is only available for Android and iOs, for Windows UWP use:

If you want as a result a byte array:

```
    public byte[] getSHA1MessageDigest(string originalKey)
    {
        IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(originalKey, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        HashAlgorithmProvider hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1);
        IBuffer sha1 = hashAlgorithm.HashData(buffer);
        byte[] newByteArray;
        CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(sha1, out newByteArray);
        return newByteArray;
    }
```

If you want as a result a string:

```
    public string getSHA1MessageDigest(string originalKey)
    {
        IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(originalKey, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        HashAlgorithmProvider hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1);
        IBuffer sha1 = hashAlgorithm.HashData(buffer);
        byte[] newByteArray;
        CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(sha1, out newByteArray);
        var sb = new StringBuilder(newByteArray.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in newByteArray)
        {
            sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```